# MYSQL GROUP BY multiple different values with specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

MYSQL Structure:

```
 ID | USERID | FRIENDID | Type
-------------------------------
 1  |   10   |    20    | Gold
 2  |   20   |    10    | Gold

 3  |   30   |    40    | Silver
 4  |   40   |    30    | Silver

 5  |   50   |    60    | Gold
 6  |   60   |    50    | Gold

 7  |   70   |    80    | Bronze
 8  |   80   |    70    | Bronze

 9  |   90   |   100    | Bronze
10  |  100   |    90    | Bronze
```

What i want is GROUP (ID 1 & ID 2) and (ID 5 & ID 6) because they are "gold" type, **NOT GROUP BY TYPE**.

Return Results:

```
 1. 10 & 20, type:gold. (GROUP)

 3. 30 & 40, type:silver.
 4. 40 & 30, type:silver.

 5. 50 & 60, type:gold. (GROUP)

 7. 70 & 80, type:bronze.
 8. 80 & 70, type:bronze.

 9. 90 & 100, type:bronze.
10. 100 & 90, type:bronze.
```

How to do that with php query?

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13bd3/1

Comment: are the ids you want to group static numbers known before hand?

Comment: if you want type = Gold then why there are more results

Comment: I'm removing the [tag:jquery] tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need to do is to add an additional grouping clause based on the type.  When it is 'gold', you get a constant.  Otherwise, you use the id:

```
select least(userid, friendid), greatest(userid, friendid), type
from t
group by least(userid, friendid), greatest(userid, friendid),
         (case when type = 'gold' then 0 else id end)
```

This does rearrange the order of the ids for non-gold types.  If ordering is important, the SQL is a little more complicated:

```
select (case when type = 'gold' then least(userid, friendid) else userid end),
       (case when type = 'gold' then greatest(userid, friendid) else friendid end),
       type
from t
group by least(userid, friendid), greatest(userid, friendid),
         (case when type = 'gold' then 0 else id end)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Gordon! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(friend_id) , type FROM mytable GROUP BY type
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13bd3/9)

Comment: Although this may not be the correct answer for this specific situation, but the group_concat saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, userid, friendid, type 
FROM (SELECT id, userid, friendid, type, 
             IF(LOWER(type) = 'gold', IF(@lasttype=(@lasttype:=TYPE), @auto, @auto:=@auto+1), @auto:=@auto+1)  indx 
      FROM tablename, (SELECT @auto:=1, @lasttype:=0) a 
      ORDER BY id) a 
GROUP BY indx;
```